# Re-train a neural network when a new category is introduced

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

Say I have a dataset with 4 classes `["dog","cat","mouse","monkey"]` and I train a CNN on a dataset to classify those classes.
A month later we get data about an "elephant" and want to include that in the network.

Of course I can just append it to my dataset and re-train the entire model - but say it takes 1 week to train the model (for some reason) and we don't want to wait that long.

What is the best way to overcome this (assume the optimal hyper-parameters are the same with or without the "elephant")? Is it simply just to create the new dataset and

1. Re-train the network from scratch?
2. Continue to train the already trained network

   2.a Don't we risk to "underfit" the "elephant" since all the iterations done before is done without the elephant?
3. something else